# Red5 flex recorder not working with Ipaddress

Tags: red5, recorder

Red5 flex recorder application running  successfully  with localhost ( localhost/myapp) but same isn't working with ipaddress (xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx/myapp). Flex component is loaded in the html page but record isn't working. Anything am i missing. Please help me out as earliest.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a red5-web.properties file in your myapp/WEB-INF folder. In that file is a setting for:
webapp.virtualHosts

Which is a list of comma separated values. For me it looked like this:

webapp.virtualHosts=localhost, 127.0.0.1, 192.168.1.2

Maybe adding your ip address to YOUR list of webapp.virtualHosts could fix the issue.